# WooCommerce Custom product type - Multiple add to cart sections issue

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I've created a custom product type in woocommerce called Booking.

Here is the code that I have:

```
class WC_Product_Booking extends WC_Product{
    /**
     * __construct function.
     *
     * @access public
     * @param mixed $product
     */
    public function __construct( $product ) {
        $this->product_type = 'booking';
        $this->supports[]   = 'ajax_add_to_cart';
        parent::__construct( $product );
        add_action('woocommerce_booking_add_to_cart', array($this, 'add_to_cart'),30);
    }

    private function show_pricing_fields(){
      ?><script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
          jQuery( '.options_group.pricing' ).addClass( 'show_if_booking' ).show();
        });
      </script><?php
    }
    /**
     * Display the add to cart button (same as for simple product)
     */
    public function add_to_cart() {
      wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php' );
    }
}
```

Right now the only problem is that the add to cart section on the product page is displayed 6 times andI cant figure out why.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

---

**@Update … Solution** *(as [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec) put me on the right track)*:

I've found a solution to this problem, using this code

```
if (! function_exists( 'woocommerce_booking_add_to_cart' ) ) {

  /**
  * Output the simple product add to cart area.
  *
  * @subpackage Product
  */

  function booking_add_to_cart() {
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php' );
  }

  add_action('woocommerce_booking_add_to_cart',  'booking_add_to_cart');
}
```

The crucial part is this action **`add_action('woocommerce_booking_add_to_cart',  'booking_add_to_cart');`**

Which puts the add to cart button once in the right place - to use it in your own custom product make an action called **`woocommerce_YOURPRODUCTTYPE_add_to_cart`**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tried to test your code on a test server, but your booking product was not showing on backend.

**Your issue could come from here:** I think you are using with `public function add_to_cart()` an existing name function, and you have to rename-it differently.

Then I have revisited your code, [based on this thread](http://jeroensormani.com/adding-a-custom-woocommerce-product-type/).

It's may be better **to extend `WC_Product_Simple` class** rather than **`WC_Product`** class, since your product uses simple product add-to-cart button template: 
*`single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php`*.

With this custom code I don't face like you Multiple add to cart sections.

> **— @Update1 —**
> But you can still keep **`WC_Product`** extended instead of **`WC_Product_Simple`**. This way, as you requested in comment, your product type will be **`"simple_booking"`** as specified in 1st and 2nd functions. That does not mean that your product is simple (**it's just a slug that you can change, changing at the same time in both places**).

> **So I have modified the code again and tested: It works…**

This is the code I use *(and I have tested)*:

```
/**
 * Register the custom product type after init
 */
function register_simple_booking_product_type() {

    /**
     * This should be in its own separate file.
     */
    class WC_Product_Booking extends WC_Product{ // <= changed back to WC_product class

        public function __construct( $product ) {

            $this->product_type = 'simple_booking';
            $this->supports[]   = 'ajax_add_to_cart';

            parent::__construct( $product );
            
            // As we extend simple product class, you may not need this anymore.
            add_action('woocommerce_booking_add_to_cart', array($this, 'simple_booking_add_to_cart'),30);

        }

        public function get_type() {
            return 'simple_booking';
        }

    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'register_simple_booking_product_type' );

// Registering the slug name (YOU can CHANGE IT)
function add_simple_booking_product( $types ){

    // Key should be exactly the same as in the class product_type parameter
    $types[ 'simple_booking' ] = __( 'Simple booking' );

    return $types;

}
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_simple_booking_product' );

/**
 * Show pricing fields for simple_booking product.
 */
function simple_booking_custom_js() {

    if ( 'product' != get_post_type() ) :
        return;
    endif;

    ?><script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
            jQuery( '.options_group.pricing' ).addClass( 'show_if_simple_booking' ).show();
        });
    </script><?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'simple_booking_custom_js' );

// Not sure you will need that (because of the change of the extended class)
function simple_booking_add_to_cart() {
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php' );
}
```

Tested this code on function.php file located in active child theme *(or theme)*.

Reference: [Adding a custom WooCommerce product type](http://jeroensormani.com/adding-a-custom-woocommerce-product-type/)

---

> **— @Update2 — The solution** *(find by the author of this question)*:

> To puts the **add-to-cart button** once in the right place (to use it in your own custom product make an action called **`woocommerce_YOURPRODUCTTYPE_add_to_cart`**), with this code:

```
if (! function_exists( 'woocommerce_booking_add_to_cart' ) ) {

  /**
  * Output the simple product add to cart area.
  *
  * @subpackage Product
  */

  function booking_add_to_cart() {
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php' );
  }

  add_action('woocommerce_booking_add_to_cart',  'booking_add_to_cart');
}
```

Comment: This solution works the only problem right now that I have is that the product type is saved as **simple** not **booking** in the database. Which for me is crucial as I display template based on the product type.

Comment: @user998757 Updated my code to feet your comment needs… It's still working

Comment: I've found a solution, your code got me on the right track, I've updated my code to make this work.