# Woocommerce Custom payment gateway callback function not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, checkout

I have been struggling with this for some time now. I almost explored all google replies etc...

Here is my code:

```
class WC_Gateway_mysolugion extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

public function __construct() {

    ...
    ...

    /* Hook IPN callback logic*/
    add_action( 'woocommerce_api_wc_gateway_mysolugion', array( $this, 'check_callback' ) );

  }

  ....

  function check_callback() {
     // other code
  }
```

The problem is that the function **`check_callback`** never get called when controll returns back to the site from payment gateway site.

What I am doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Payment gateways should be created as additional plugins that hook into WooCommerce. Inside the plugin, you need to create a class **after plugins are loaded** *(or alternatively **at initialisation** if is on function.php file of your active theme, see below)*.

So your code will look to this:

```
// for a plugin (the better choice)
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'init_mysolugion_gateway' );

// OR for theme function.php file
// add_action( 'init', 'init_mysolugion_gateway' );

function init_mysolugion_gateway() {

    class WC_Gateway_mysolugion extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

        public function __construct() {

            // ...
            // ...

            /* Hook IPN callback logic*/
            add_action( 'woocommerce_api_wc_gateway_mysolugion', array( $this, 'check_callback' ) );

        }

    }

}
```

As well as defining your class, you need to also tell WooCommerce (WC) that it exists. Do this by filtering woocommerce_payment_gateways:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_gateway_mysolugion' );
function add_gateway_mysolugion( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_mysolugion'; 
    return $methods;
}
```

Then you can add your callback function and this should work now:

```
function check_callback() {
   // other code
}
```

References:

- [WooCommerce DOCS - Payment Gateway API: **Creating a basic payment gateway**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/#section-2)
- [An example of theme init hook code with extending a WC class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432736/woocommerce-custom-product-type-multiple-add-to-cart-sections-issue/38439362#38439362)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I appreciate it. I know all of this and have already implemented. I created a plugin for this. and all the above code(in original question) is wrapped in side an intializing class. I put only a simplified ver of my code here. I tried all options I could think of.

Comment: @A.Ali Kindly, Is better to make a link to a more consistant code, with better explanations and more details, giving too references that you have tried, what is working and what is not… Because is not possible to really help only with the few details of your "poor" question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @LoicTheAztec, for replying and helping. However, I found the reason why it was not working for me.

In my case I moved the callback function out of the mail gateway class and it started working. Simply put it in separate class and initiate that class in constructor of the main gateway class. that's it.

cheers,

Comment: Impossible to guess that with the information and code you left in your question…

Comment: well, I had legal obligations so that I could not show full script. However, from the piece of code I wrote in my original question, it is obvious that I was putting callback function within gateway class :D

Comment: @LoicTheAztec is that so serious to have me accept your answer? If so, I'll click that tick button, but honestly your answer (although it could be true) didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I still up voted your reply, although didn't accept it.